# Problems getting Firebase set up in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

Really having a tough time getting Firebase stood up in xcode. I'm trying to get a project going using Swift with the instructions [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/setup.html).

Per the instructions I create a new project using Templates. I choose Firebase >  Single View Application, which creates a project. From here I have problems.

1. I try to create a bridging header by first creating a temp objc file. I'm never presented with the option to actually create the bridging header during that process. Only the objc file is created. I manually create a header file using [these instructions](https://bohemianpolymorph.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/manually-adding-a-swift-bridging-header/).
2. I note some strangely name view controller files are created which fail the build due to containing multiple syntax errors (___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___ViewController.h and ___VARIABLE_classPrefix:identifier___ViewController.m).
3. Main.storyboard won't open. I get a message saying it is corrupt.

What is going on here? I'm able to stand up a normal non-Firebase project via templates. I'm new to Swift/XCode dev so I'm not sure if I'm missing a step. Is it possible to install this SDK via templates?

Comment: The templates are broken with XCode 6.1. You'll need to use one of the other ways to create a Firebase project until we release the fixed templates.

Answer (score -3):

Not quite sure what you've done here lol.

Best to use this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin) when new to swift.

To create a header file go to 'file' -> 'new' -> 'file' -> In the IOS tab 'Header file'.

I've been having problems with Firebase in Xcode 8 Beta so probably best to stick with Xcode 7 until official release.